# Can you create template pages in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have the following 2 pages:

```
---
<!-- pages/apple.md -->
title: Apple Nutrition Info
permalink: /info/apple
---

{% assign fruit = site.data.info.apple %}
Carbs: {{fruit.carbs}}
Sugar: {{fruit.sugar}}

![Apple](/assets/images/apple.png)
```

```
---
<!-- pages/orange.md -->
title: Orange Nutrition Info
permalink: /info/orange
---

{% assign fruit = site.data.info.orange %}
Carbs: {{fruit.carbs}}
Sugar: {{fruit.sugar}}

![Orange](assets/images/orange.png)
```

Since the pages' content are almost identical, is it possible to template the entire page itself, and somehow pass data like "apple", "orange", "banana" to the page?

I would love to do something like this:

```
---
<!-- pages/info.md -->
title: {{args.fruit | capitalize}} Nutrition Info
permalink: /info/{{args.fruit}}
---

{% assign fruit = site.data.info.{{args.fruit}} %}
Carbs: {{fruit.carbs}}
Sugar: {{fruit.sugar}}

![{{args.fruit | capitalize}}](assets/images/{{args.fruit}}.png)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

A bypass is to use [*collections*](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/09-collections/) instead of [*pages*](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/)+[*data*](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/). (The doc on *collections* offers an example about `authors` with `name`s and `position`s, similar to your `fruits` with `carbs` and `sugar`.)

`_config.yml`:

```yaml
# …… (title, domain, plugins, etc.)

collections:
  fruits:
    output: true
    permalink: /fruits/:name/

defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
      type: fruits
    values:
      layout: fruit
```

(Permalinks pattern for *collections* can be different from *pages*, see [Permalinks | Jekyll Doc](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#collections) if necessary.)

`_layouts/fruit.md`:

```markdown
---
layout: default
---

- Carbs: {{ page.carbs }}
- Sugar: {{ page.sugar }}

![{{ page.name | capitalize }}](assets/images/{{page.name}}.png)
```

`_fruits/apple.md`:

```markdown
---
name: apple
carbs: ○○
sugar: □□
---
```